Difficulties connecting to Docker Quickstart instance using node js on pubnet
I have been trying the Docker Quickstart image for submitting transactions on the pubnet and, hopefully, also retrieving data. I (believe) I have increased storage capacity and also set CATCHUP_RECENT to 1000000 in my stellar-core.cfg so that data from a while back will be stored.
Before I changed it to 1000000, I was getting the 503 still ingesting error when doing a server.loadAccount, now I simply get an Error: connect ETIMEDOUT instead. If I change the IP address to something random this persists, so it seems that node does does not recognize the existence of the image.
I have started with the command
docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -v "/home/user/stellar:opt/stellar" --name stellar stellar/quickstart --pubnet

The ip address I got from docker inspect after getting the instance id using docker ps is 172.17.0.2.
in my code I use the network passphrase
var server = new StellarSdk.Horizon.Server('http://172.17.0.2:8000', {allowHttp: true});

What could be going wrong?
Somewhat similar thread/issue:
Unable to connect to horizon via JavaScript SDK
EDIT: I changed the IP address to 127.0.0.1 instead of using the Docker IP, now I get the Still ingesting error, which is some progress. Will see if I get past this.
EDIT 2: I am now getting 502 bad gateway on one Docker instance which runs on Linux.
EDIT 3: Now it works on a Windows instance; I am correctly loading everything now. 127.0.0.1 is the IP address to use regardless of what IP the Docker instance has.
